# RemoteServiceException : Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Tags: android, android-service

I implemented service on my app and sometimes I get error . I checked stakoverflow posts and I found I should run startForeground() on both oncreate and onstartcommand method . but I have problem , I can not run this code on my oncreate because for run startForeground() I should get data from intent on start command and I don't have access to this data on my create .
here is my code . can some one help me to get rid of this error ?

my activity code:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("RadioAddress", channelAddress);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(PlayerActivity.this, serviceIntent);
```

my service code :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private String CHANNEL_ID = "channelId";
private NotificationManager notifManager;
public static final String DELETE_EXTRA_KEY = "delete";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
public SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
private String radioAddress, radioName, radioIcon, radioSourceType;
private Context context;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
private ClipData.Item item;
private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
private long playerPosition;
private boolean playWhenReady = true;
private CloseReceiver closeReceiver;
private Notification servNotification;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            radioAddress = intent.getStringExtra("RadioAddress");
            initializePlayer(radioAddress);
   return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    releasePlayer();
    unregisterReceiver(closeReceiver);
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void initializePlayer(String MyAddress) {
    if (exoPlayer == null) {
        DefaultTrackSelector myTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(context);
        DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters myDefaultTrackParam = myTrackSelector.buildUponParameters().build();
        myTrackSelector.setParameters(myDefaultTrackParam);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(app.myPlayer.player_lib.R.string.app_name)));

        MediaSourceFactory mediaSourceFactory =
                new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory);
        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
                .setTrackSelector(myTrackSelector)
                .build();
    }


    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(MyAddress));
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    exoPlayer.prepare();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String offerChannelName = "Service Radio";
        String offerChannelDescription = "Playing Radio";

       int offerChannelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notifChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, offerChannelName, offerChannelImportance);
        notifChannel.setDescription(offerChannelDescription);
        notifManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notifManager.createNotificationChannel(notifChannel);

    }

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), app.myPlayer.player_lib.R.layout.radio_custom_notification);

    initCloseReceiver();
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                NotificationCompat.Builder sNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(app.myPlayer.player_lib.R.drawable.ic_myPlayer_logo)
                        .setContent(contentView)
                  

                        .addAction(0, "stop", createClosePendingIntent());

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    sNotifBuilder.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
                else
                    sNotifBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW);

                servNotification = sNotifBuilder.build();


                startForeground(131512, servNotification);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
   
}

public void initCloseReceiver() {
    closeReceiver = new CloseReceiver(this);
    registerReceiver(closeReceiver, new IntentFilter(CloseReceiver.ACTION));
}


public PendingIntent createClosePendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CloseReceiver.ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
}

public static class CloseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION = "stop_service";

    Service service;

    public CloseReceiver(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        service.stopForeground(true);
        service.stopSelf();
    }

}


private void releasePlayer() {
    if (exoPlayer != null) {
        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer = null;
    }
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you posting the `Notification` and calling`startForeground()` in an `AsyncTask`? There's no reason for that. You can do all of that inline.

Comment: What "error" do you get? Please post the exception message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `startForeground()` in `onCreate()`. There is no reason to do that. The call to `onCreate()` will be followed immediately by a call to `onStartCommand()`.